# is it possible to make an application for video calls in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, video, video-streaming, video-capture, videochat

I need to write an application with video chats (1:1), and i know Angular. There are tons of SDKs for Angular(or web) to handle video calls(like e.g. twilio.com, agora.io?). But my client need mobile app. It's possible to write native app in Ionic with video calls support? However, do I have to use something more professional like flutter to achieve this?

Is there any ready SDK to handle this in Ionic?

I am looking, I am looking for and I cannot find anything. And I have to make quick decisions in part.

Please help me :)

Comment: check this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-iosrtc

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

You can use the camera and the microphone with Ionic (in native or pwa mode).

Ionic fully supports Angular and Angular components.

I recommend you the use of notifications like Google FCM to notify the caller.

You can trigger an action directly from the notification (app in background or in app which is not the same).